# When the choice space is X=N*[-1,1], how do you determine whether the following lexicographic preference can be represented by a utility function

Tags: mathematical-economics

Here is the lexicographic preference be given,
[image]

And here is the choice space,
[image]
I'm really struggled with determining this proof, can someone help to solve the problem or give some hint? Thanks so much!

(p.s. there is no typo or other mistakes in this question and lexicographic preference)

Comment: That is not the usual definition of lexicographic preferences; whoever gave this problem has probably made a typo here. See page 6 [here](https://books.openbookpublishers.com/10.11647/obp.0204.04.pdf) for the standard definition.

Comment: These are certainly not lexicographic preferences as usually defined. Anyways, they are representable by $u(n,x)=-3n+x$.